# How to add click's listener for app's icon on ActionBar in Android?

Tags: java, android

There is the following code:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.basket);
```

Now I want to set listener for clicking by this icon. Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below code at onCreate() of Activity

```
mActionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And here is listener

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish(); // Or do you own task 
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

---

Read more at [Add Up Button for Low-level Activities](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav). [***And Adding the Action Bar***](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) is a very good resource about ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of making custom title bar:

1.If you are making your custom Title by this way

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//xml class of your mainActivity
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title_bar);
                   /////custom_title_bar is xml of which type you want to make your title bar
```

Then just find the id of widgets that are in custom_title_bar and perform action as you perform action for your mainactivity xml.

just take this as they are widgets of your activity xml

1. If you are making your title bar by changing in menu.xml file

values -> menu.xml

```
<item 
        android:id="@+id/show" 
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/show"
        android:icon="@drawable/showbutn">

    </item>
```

where `android:showAsAction="always"`,this line place item on the title bar

then in your mainactivity class overide onOptionsItemSelected method as:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.show:
            ///////perform your action what you want by clicking on item
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

That's it....